# How to approach re-usability when soft deleting

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, oop

We have an MVC4 project in .NET and SQL Server. We are showing a listing of  people, right from the listing we can inactivate a user, or we can click on edit and you see all fields except the inactive flag (we show the flag on the listing).

My co-workers created a stored procedure to specifically change the active flag for a user and I thought this is incorrect from a purely object-oriented perspective.

We have a class called Person with Person_SID, Name, Active, which we populate when creating or editing then we pass it to the business layer like this

```
PersonBusiness.Save(p)
```

p is being an instance of Person. shouldn't we do the same wen activating or inactivating a user?

```
public void SetFlag(int person_sid, bool flag)
{
    Person p = null;
    if((p = Get(person_sid)) != null)//check if user still exists
    {
        p.Active = flag;
        Save(p);
    }
}
```

Instead of having a method that calls a stored procedure to specifically do this causing us to now maintain two stored procedures and be redundant like:

```
repo.SetActive(person_sid, flag);
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Having two or more stored procedures for a set of tasks such as yours is a completely viable approach, and developer's point of view is rather irrelevant here. The only thing that matters here are business requirements, and they can justify many decisions a developer would consider sub-optimal.

Just as an example, a business might want to require additional (separate) permissions for a user who is going to (de)activate a `Person`, compared to a general edit. Normally, I would create separate roles and grant them permissions to corresponding objects, like:

```
create role 'manager';
go
create role 'supervisor';
go
grant execute on dbo.person_Edit to [manager];
go
grant execute on dbo.person_Activate to [supervisor];
go
```

Sure, you can add an equivalent check in your code, such as:

```
if is_rolemember('supervisor') = 0 and @Active != @OldActive
  throw 'Membership in the "supervisor" role is required to deactivate a person.';
```

However, such a solution will bring many other problems - you can't use the built-in SQL Server security system to set permissions, because the check is now in your code. And if the business rule will change at a later time, the DBA can't simply adjust permissions, (s)he has to alter the code of the procedure. And if, for some reason, such a requirement differs across database instances... well, you got the idea.

In short, consult with the business whether they need such a separation of access, or anything else that might benefit from it, and if they don't, use it as an argument for getting rid of additional procedure. Otherwise, the existing solution might be better left unchanged.